# Why am I getting ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

The following code gives me Value Error:

```py
major_males=[]

for row in recent_grads:
    if recent_grads['Men']>recent_grads['Women']:
        major_males.append(recent_grads['Major'])
display(major_males)
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `recent_grads` is a dataframe, then this is how your for loop would look like

```py
major_males=[]

for i, row in recent_grads.iterrows():
    if row['Men']>row['Women']:
        major_males.append(row['Major'])
display(major_males)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are comparing a series and not a value. 
I guess your intension was `if row['Men'] > row['Women']`

Secondly it will be more efficient to do

```py
major_males = recent_grads[recent_grads.Men > recent_grads.Women].Major.to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that, while you're iterating over the data frame, you're not using the `row` variable. Instead, try:

```
major_males=[]

for row in recent_grads:
    if row['Men']>row['Women']:
        major_males.append(row['Major'])
display(major_males)
```

You get the error because it's not meaningful to compare all the `Men` values to all the `Women` values: instead you want to compare one specific value of each at a time, which is what the change does.

Comment: tried that but am getting: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I think he missed the `.iterrows()` part.