# Create a pandas series based on conditional values in another series

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a pandas series based on the values in the 'overall' series.

```
if relevant.overall <= 2:
        relevant['Sentiment'] = 'Negative'
    elif relevant.overall == 3:
        relevant['Sentiment'] = 'Neutral'
    else: #Score of 4 or 5
        relevant['Sentiment'] = 'Positive'
```

This was my code for which I got the error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). 
Then I checked on some previously asked question and tried the accepted answer on this: [Why am I getting ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350625/why-am-i-getting-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-emp).

```
Sentiment = []    
for i, row in relevant.iterrows(): 
    if row.overall <= 2:
        Sentiment.append('Negative')
    elif row.overall == 3:
        Sentiment.append('Neutral')
    else: #Score of 4 or 5
        Sentiment.append('Positive')
```

This is my code now for which I'm getting, 'str' object has no attribute 'append'.

Comment: check `np.select`

Comment: That worked but with a warning. __main__:6: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead @jezrael

Comment: How is created `relevant` ?

Comment: amazon_review = pd.read_json('Books_small.json', lines=True)
relevant = amazon_review[['reviewText', 'overall']] @jezrael

Comment: then change `relevant = amazon_review[['reviewText', 'overall']]` to `relevant = amazon_review[['reviewText', 'overall']].copy()`

Comment: That worked, thanks! @jezrael